# Setup testcontainers for micronaut for mongodb

Tags: kotlin, micronaut, testcontainers

I'm playing around with Testcontainers, Micronaut and Kotlin and somehow Micronaut doesn't want replace to the dynamic port of the MongoDB that I'm starting and its working so far.

I haven't replaced the `application-test.yml` under (/src/test/resources)

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: abc
mongodb:
  connection-pool:
    max-size: 20
  uri: mongodb://${MONGO_HOST:localhost}:${MONGO_PORT}
```

Here is my setup code:

```
// class .....
companion object {
        private lateinit var embeddedServer: EmbeddedServer
        lateinit var mongoContainer: MongoContainer

        @BeforeAll
        @JvmStatic
        internal fun beforeAll() {
            mongoContainer = MongoContainer()
            mongoContainer.start()
            assertThatPortIsAvailable(mongoContainer)

            System.setProperty("MONGO_HOST", mongoContainer.containerIpAddress)
            System.setProperty("MONGO_PORT", mongoContainer.getPort().toString())

            println(System.getProperties()) // THE ENV VAR IS AVAILABLE HERE
            println("aaaaaaaa" + mongoContainer.getPort())

            embeddedServer = ApplicationContext.run(EmbeddedServer::class.java, PropertySource.of(
                    "test", mapOf(
                    "mongo.uri" to mongoContainer.containerIpAddress,
                    "mongo.port" to mongoContainer.getPort())
            ))
        }
```

Error message: Message: Could not resolve placeholder ${MONGO_PORT}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats helped me in in order to run Testcontainers with micronauts in Kotlin.

```
import a.b.c.model.NewOffer
import a.b.c.model.QuantityType
import io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.annotation.MicronautTest
import io.micronaut.test.support.TestPropertyProvider
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance
import org.testcontainers.containers.MongoDBContainer
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers
import javax.inject.Inject

@Testcontainers
@MicronautTest()
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
internal class OfferRepositoryTest() : TestPropertyProvider {

    @Inject
    private lateinit var offerRepository: OfferRepository

    private val mongoDBContainer: MongoDBContainer = MongoDBContainer("mongo:4").apply { start() }

    @Test
    internal fun getEmptyOffers() {
        val find = offerRepository.find()
        assertThat(find).isEmpty()
    }

    override fun getProperties(): MutableMap<String, String> {
        return mutableMapOf(
                "MONGO_HOST" to mongoDBContainer.containerIpAddress,
                "MONGO_PORT" to "${mongoDBContainer.getMappedPort(27017)}"
        )
    }
}
```

and the src/main/resources/application.yml looks as generated by micronaut

```
mongodb:
  connection-pool:
    max-size: 20
  uri: mongodb://${MONGO_HOST:localhost}:${MONGO_PORT:27017}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are better off providing the complete `mongodb.uri` by implementing `TestPropertyProvider`.

And I think you want to get the actual port with `mongoContainer.getMappedPort(27017)`.

Comment: Thx, the TestPropertyProvider interface helped in solving the issue https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/ I've added my solution as an answer